# How to append xml data inside xml file with shell script?

Tags: xml, shell-scripting

script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u root -pmysql --xml << eof
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb"  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema='database_name';
eof
```

I am getting xml data with above script. How may I get this data in xml file ?

Comment: `script > file`? It seems that is what https://serverfault.com/a/250316/407952 effectively does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u root -pmysql --xml > /home/test/Desktop/temp.xml << eof
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb"  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema='database_name';
eof
```